# How to change xPage combobox dropdown arrow background color?

Tags: css, xpages

Combobox arrow looks good in Chrome and IE but not good in FF.
Here is my simple xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:comboBox id="inputComboBoxSearch" defaultValue="0" value="0"
    style="height:60px; width:120px; text-align:right; box-shadow:none; border-radius:0; display:inline;">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Search by" itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Date" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="City" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:comboBox>
</xp:view>  

And here is how it look like in different browsers. How to change FF style so it is same as on Chrome?
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `styleClass=""` to your xp:comboBox. Then, arrow's gray background on Firefox is gone.

If you want to look your combobox on all browsers the same then use Dojo and add `dojoType="dijit/form/Select"` instead.

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="inputComboBoxSearch"
    defaultValue="0"
    value="0"
    style="height:60px; width:120px;"
    dojoType="dijit/form/Select">
```

Comment: Adding styleClass="" to my example above doesn't help in FF.
dojoType="dijit/form/Select" just breaks everything set in style="...

Comment: Which theme do you use? It worked for me with theme "Platform default" and "webstandard" and FF version 51.

Comment: Setting styleClass="" worked for me too on FF 51.0.1, Dom 9.0.1FP7 and it's a lot neater than my solution.

Comment: I use "Bootstrap3" theme. But it doesn't work with "Platform default" and "webstandard" as well. Dropdown still looks weird in FF (45.7.0) Domino 9.0.1FP7.

Comment: I can confirm that `styleClass=""` doesn't work in Firefox' old version 45.7.0.  But, if you delete `border-radius:0;` from *style* then `styleClass=""` works in Firefox 45.7.0 too - with theme "Platform default" and "webstandard" but not "Bootstrap3".

Comment: well, I need to use Bootstrap3 theme. Is there a way I can make it custom especially for FF?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with the *border* property. See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/pvfyt).  XPage combo boxes inherit a *border* property by way of a ".lotusForm select" css style application from core.css. The only way I found to avoid this was to set the createForm property on the XPage to *false* **AND** disable theming on  the combobox by setting *disableTheme* to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    createForm="false">


    <xp:comboBox id="inputComboBoxSearch" defaultValue="0" value="0"
        style="height:60px; width:120px; text-align:right; display:inline; "
        disableTheme="true" >
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Search by" itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Date" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="City" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:comboBox>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The dropdown looks weird in FF.. .Anything in app properties I need to adjust?

Comment: @John, it does work for your Firefox 45.7.0 and theme "Bootstrap3" if you delete `border-radius:0;` from style. You don't need to set `createForm="false"`. Just adding `disableTheme="true"` is enough. So, @Simon, your solution is for John's case the better one :)

Comment: Simon's example doesn't work. Have you tried it with Bootstrap3 theme enabled in application?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix. No need to disable theme or Create form param. Works with Bootstrap3 theme...

```
height:60px; 
width:120px; 
display:inline;
background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
background-position: 95px 20px;
```